# Question on Sample Sizes & Reporting

Tags: statistics, sampling

My organization has a policy that any survey response with a sample size LT 6 is not reported. This is applied to the answer, not the whole question, e.g. in the "state" example below we would suppress the response "Texas" and in the "gender" example, we would suppress "male."

My question is: is this the right way to be doing this or should we be applying sample size rules to the total respondents of a question (e.g. the 23 "state" variable and 12 in the "gender" variable). To suppress just the category doesn't make a lot of sense to me. E.g., with gender, you can suppress the "male" response -- but the percent female is based on the percent male so it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Sorry if this is a dumb question but appreciate any help out there!

Variable "state" with unweighted frequencies
California: 9
Texas: 4
Other: 10
Total: 23

Variable "gender" with unweighted frequencies
Male: 2
Female: 10 
Total: 12

Comment: If this is a disclosure/privacy question then you you face a secondary disclosure problem that knowing the total and the rest of the components you can deduce the suppressed number.   With your states you can say "California 9, Not-California 14, Total 23"; with the gender example you can say "Female 10" or "Total 12" but not both, and usually the total is more useful information than a component

Comment: That makes sense - thank you!